# Http authentication not working in linux hosted website

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a linux hosted website, i am trying to use the below code for http-authentication for access to one confidential page, but it doesn't seem to work, everytime i enter username and password, the authentication box pops up again! Can anybody tell me where m i going wrong?

```
 <?php
 // User name and password for authentication

$username='username';
$password='password';


if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||
($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !=$username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !=$password)) 
{
 // The user name/password are incorrect so send the authentication headers
   header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Web Page:The Freedom Square Of Internet"');
  exit('<h2>My Web page</h2>Sorry, you must enter a valid user name and password to access this page.');
  }
?>
```

Comment: You accept as correct answer button is not working either.

Comment: You asked a lot of questions on SO, but never accepted one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that your server 'eats' the 'Authorization' header, spitting out the contents of `$_SERVER` can help you get a better idea of what's going on. What server are you using?

Here's a `mod_rewrite` solution for Apache if you're using fastcgi and the above is your issue:
http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Catalyst-Runtime-5.80012/lib/Catalyst/Engine/FastCGI.pm#Authorization_header_with_mod_fastcgi_or_mod_cgi

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1,PT]
```

You can then quite simply process the Authorization header if PHP doesn't do it for you.

Comment: its apache, how do u spit out the contents?

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) or print_r($_SERVER) should help :)

Comment: I am sorry Benjie, I am a php newbie, could you explain me, how this exactly works?

Comment: after your header(), but before your exit(), insert the following: `print_r($_SERVER);` and then paste the result here (you'll need to enter a false username and password and then press cancel the second time).

Comment: it didn't help, login prompt pops up everytime. even after entering false credentials!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The `print_r($_SERVER)` is intended to give us more information to help debug the issue, not to fix the problem. (Don't forget to cancel the login popup the second/third/etc times.) Please paste the output of that command somewhere and link us to it :)

Comment: "Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.5 Server at MYWEBPAGE Port 80                                      Sorry, you must enter a valid user name and password to access this page."          This is what i get

Comment: That at least confirms that your issue is fastcgi and that my mod_rewrite solution should work. Look into .htaccess files if you are unable to add the rules to your apache configuration.